# Find values which make a matrix singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find all the values of c for which the following matrix is singular:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & c & c \\ c & c & c \\ 2 & c & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Write down its determinant as a function of $c$.

Comment: You can create a singular matrix by having a zero row or zero column, or by making two rows equal, or by making two columns equal. These aren't the only ways a matrix can be singular, but they can sometimes be found by quick inspection. The determinant will likely be a cubic in c (c in all three rows and columns, no obvious cancellation) so spotting a solution could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also apply Gaussian Elimination to get:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & c & c \\
0 & c^2 - c & c - c^2 \\
0 & 0 & -c + 3\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This matrix is singular if any element on the diagonal is zero, i.e, if:
$$ c^2 - c = 0  \text{ or } -c+3 = 0 $$
which is equivalent to computing the determinant..

Comment: Thats an interesting way of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

The determinant equals $3c-4c^2+c^3$. Compute it by means of Laplace's algorithm, for instance. Otherwise, use the standard trick for $3 \times 3$ matrices. Hence the matrix is singular when $c=0$. Now you can divide the equation $3c-4c^2+c^3=0$ by $c$, and find the other solutions $c=1$ and $c=3$.